# WinForms application appears out of the desktop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a notebook that I plug in to an external monitor at work and have both screens. I believe if my app was running on the monitor the last time, when I launch it again (after a Windows Hibernate) at home (where I don't have an extra monitor) the application starts out of bounds, like in the external monitor and I need to [struggle](https://superuser.com/questions/53585/how-to-move-windows-that-open-up-offscreen) to get it back in place.

As a developer, is there anything I'm doing wrong? is it a Windows issue?

Comment: what do you do wrt to persisting the apps state?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Form.StartPosition` ?

Answer (score -1):

Using whatever method you prefer, when you close the app you can save Location, Height and Width.  Then when you launch the app you can reset those values.

Closing the form:

```
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                settings.Height = Height;
                settings.Width = Width;
                settings.Location = Location;
            }
            else
            {
                settings.Height = RestoreBounds.Height;
                settings.Width = RestoreBounds.Width;
                settings.Location = RestoreBounds.Location;
            }
```

Opening the form:

```
                Location = settings.Location;
                Height = settings.Height;
                Width = settings.Width;
```